# When an NFT from one collection gets transfered, transfer certain NFTs from other collection automatically

Tags: contract-development, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

There're 2 future NFT collections.

Is it possible to create the contracts for them in such a way that whenever an NFT of collection_1 `c1` gets, some NFTs from collection_2 `c2` of the same account get transfered automatically to the receiver as well?

Meaning, even when a user decides to send an NFT from `c1` from his wallet *manually*, without calling a special function `myTransferNFTOf2Collections(...)` which I may create. In other words, it should occur in all possible cases, without any additional effort from the user.

*option #1:*

the contract for `collection_1` has been created in the past, and therefore can't be changed now. Would this be possible still?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create NFTs bound to other NFTs. Let's say you have an original collection A and a "mirrored" collection B.

By borrowing the `ownerOf` function from A, we can make one in B like this:

```
function ownerOf(
    uint256 tokenId
) public view virtual override returns (address) {
    return IERC721(originalCollection).ownerOf(tokenId);
}
```

you've effectively bound all new NFTs to the owners of the original collection. This is how Cyberkongz have "airdropped" a copy of the original version with on-chain metadata to every holder. When an original is transferred, the internal mapping update happens in one smart-contract, but it is reflected in both. You don't have to use any expensive storage at all which makes it very cheap to deploy.

Note that you may have to fire a specific "batch mint" event when the new contract is deployed in order for off-chain indexers to display the NFTs in user wallets. You can read more about it in a [blog by 0xInuarashi](https://0xinuarashi.medium.com/introducing-on-chain-kongz-ac82f68d15a).

Comment: I don't understand. Where will `function ownerOf(...)` have to be placed?

Comment: The `ownerOf` function is part of the IERC721 standard, every NFT smart-contract needs to have it. Dive deeper into the implementation on OpenZeppelin's GitHub and it will all make more sense.

Comment: That's not what I asked about

Comment: I've asked about 1-n rather than 1-1